# If $n$ people are moving to $n$ chairs, what is the maximum number of intersections of their paths of motion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I generated this sequence while working on this problem. Say we have $n$ people trying to sit in $n$ chairs. The chairs and people are all at lattice points (people at $(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),\dotsc,(n-1,0)$ and chairs at $(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),\dotsc,(n-1,1)$).
What is the maximum number of intersection points between paths of motion from a person's original position to a chair?

I have the solution for $n = 5$, and generated up until $n = 10$. Can you have any insight into developing a formula?

[image: Solution for n = 5]

Comment: $156 - 8037x/20 + 2047051x^2/5040 - 77047x^3/360 + 188713x^4/2880 - 4339x^5/360 + 1889x^6/1440 - 7x^7/90 + 13x^8/6720$ by Lagrange Interpolation, giving 190 for the next number. More seriously, you can't expect single one answer if you don't provide more information about your question.

Comment: WolframAlpha does not computing a possible formula for your sequence: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C+2%2C+5%2C+8%2C+13%2C+17%2C+23%2C+30%2C+39%2C+...

Comment: So the fourth entry in the sequence ($8$) corresponds to $n=5$, assuming your figure depicts the maximum number of intersections for $n=5$?

Comment: Yes, the fourth entry is n=5. I used a computer program to generate all possible permutations of bijections between points on y=1 and y=0.

Comment: It would be useful to note that this was added as a sequence in OEIS: [A332774](https://oeis.org/A332774).

Comment: Assuming straight paths, any one path can intersect another path only once. Thus for $n$ paths, the maximum number of intrresections is simply $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{(n)(n-1)}{2}$. If the rightmost person traverses to the leftmost chair, then the second rightmost person crosses to the second leftmost chair, their paths intersect. When the next rightmost crosses to the next leftmost, he must cross all previous paths. This holds true for all remaining crossings. So it is possible to achieve the theoretical maximum, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{(n)(n-1)}{2}$.

Comment: I just read the unedited post, and the problem with the original question is that it did not present a sequence that corresponded to the maximum number of intersections, just the maximum that the OP could identify by trial and error.